# Can't make i18n run

Tags: javascript, html, json, internationalization, i18next

I am creating a website with HTML5 and CSS, not using CMS. My next goal was to make the website in many languages so I searched and found many libraries. I am newbie to this and went for the easiest one or the one with more comments, examples...

So I took i18next, but I also tried i18n, i18next.amd... Right now I am stuck because I was following a few tutorials and cant make this work... Everytime I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: i18n is not defined

So I created an empty project just to make this work and learn how to do it. This new project is really light. The structure is:

- index.html
- locales

  - en

    - translation.json
  - es

    - translation.json
  - default

    - translation.json
- js

  - jquery.min.js
  - i18next.min.js

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    
 
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18next.min.js" ></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var options ={ 
     lng: "en" ,  
     resGetPath: './../locales/__lng__/__ns__.json'
  };

  i18n.init(options, function(t) {
       $(".nav").i18n();
  });
 </script>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1">asd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2">asd</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and all of the JSON files are like this:

```
{
"app": {
"name": "i18next"
},
"nav": {
"home": "Home",
"page1": "Page One",
"page2": "Page Two"
}
}
```

I wish someone can help me, and I will really appreciate. (sorry for my english btw)

Tutorials I mentioned:
http://i18next.github.io/i18next/
http://jsbin.com/yaxofuhuzu/1/edit?html,js,output
www.davidhamannmedia.com/en/post-i18next-an-easy-to-use-translation-javascript-library

And many more...

Comment: First try closing your script tags correctly (`<script />` should be `<script></script>`). [They're supposed to be closed that way.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: Ok done, I think that was a typo I made before posting this question. Thanks but still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for this library is a mess, mostly because the author decided to rewrite it from version 1.x to 2.x and the API has changed drastically. The documentation you can now find on http://i18next.com/docs/ refers to version 2.x, while a lot of the blog and stackoverflow articles refer to version 1.x, adding to the confusion. To add insult to injury, I can't find any complete documentation for version 1.x anymore (which by the way, is less than a year old).

Now, to answer your question, the options and API you seem to be using are from version 1.x (for example, `resGetPath` doesn't exist in version 2.x). Also, in 2.x, `i18n` has been replaced by `i18next`.

On the bright side, the author seems to reply fast to questions, so you might as well open an issue on the project github page. Or check this:

https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/618

Comment: Looks like the old documentation is hosted on the [project's GitHub.io](http://i18next.github.io/i18next/)

Comment: Great! :) I don't know how you found this, google search didn't return this page for me.